# How to place a comma in string based on specific character position in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to place comma after every 4 characters of a string.

Ex : [00030004002900310057010801380139022403680374]

Need result as : [0003,0004,0029,0031,0057,0108,0138,0139,0224,0368,0374]

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select input_col, 
  (select string_agg(val, ',' order by offset)
  from unnest(regexp_extract_all(input_col, r'.{4}')) val with offset
  ) output_col
from data
```

if applied to sample in your question - output is

[image]